# Change background for search results

Tags: css, blogger

I found a "mistake" in the theme of my blog. I would like to modify
the CSS code of the searching function result's messages because its background comes together with the **data:messages.showAll** data layout tag.

So how do I change the following layout tags backgrounds?

```
Data:view.search.resultsMessageHtml

And

Data:messages.showAll
```

My theme is 'Soho' and after searching I got back a blue background with two messages. I would like to separate this two messages with a black straight line or different backgrounds.

Have I any chance do fix that?

Comment: Your question is not clear, plus you need to post more code and errors and tell us what you have tried already

Comment: paste a picture for the message and your site link to check

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should be able to achieve what you require -

```
.post-filter-message {
  position: relative;
}

.home-link-container {
  background: #f0f0f0; /* The background color of your choice */
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.home-link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Add this into your theme code via Theme tab  Customise  Advanced  Add CSS

[image: different background]